# Scala Read Json as Map[String,T]

Tags: scala, jackson

I am trying to read below json structure using scala code but i am not able to read it as case class object.

```
  "a": {
    "source": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "basePath": "/Users/bounce/anuj/data/test",
        "granularity": "None"
      },
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "basePath": "/Users/bounce/anuj/data/test1",
        "granularity": "None"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the code that i am using :

```
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    val mapData = mapper.readValue(source, classOf[Map[String,FactConfig]])


      @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
      case class Source(name: String,
                  basePath: String,
                  granularity: String)

      case class FactConfig(
      source : List[Source])

      val d = mapData.get("a").asInstanceOf[FactConfig]
```

When I m trying to convert it to FactConfig object I am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 cannot be cast to com.bounce.dp.etl.config.FactConfig
```

Please suggest to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should specify both in the question as in the tags which library are you using and if you are willing to change the library or not.

Comment: The current input sample misses the opening `{` bracket before `"a"`. Is it a copy/paste error or the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

In both Java and Scala world we normally lose generic type information during compilation. By using `classOf` operator jackson is not aware what should it do with map keys and values. The workaround is to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`, namely

```
val mapData = mapper.readValue(source, new TypeReference[Map[String, FactConfig]] {})
```

Comment: After doing like this i am not able to event get value from map . when i am trying this . val d = mapData.get("a")  its throwing error Error:(47, 20) value get is not a member of Nothing

Comment: @Anujjain I tried this and it works for me. I'm using latest version of jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-module-scala (2.10.1)